# Azure Diagnostics vs ELMAH use cases?

Tags: elmah, azure-diagnostics

I've used ELMAH on standalone (non-Azure) projects. For Azure related projects, I came across the Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) library.

At face value they appear to do the same things (with Azure Diagnostics doing more low level stuff too) so I wanted to ask if, from a technical perspective, one is more suited towards a particular type of workload/design than the other? Or are they fairly similar in use cases and it's just a vanilla-vs-chocolate (i.e. personal preference) thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think of these two things as substitutes.  The diagnostics agent that is on the machine is there to simply facilitate moving traces, counters, and other information into storage.  ELMAH is more of a logging framework.  If you were to configure ELMAH to log to Trace, it would actually work in concert with the AzureDiagnosticsTraceListener and messages output through ELMAH would be transferred to storage (assuming you configured the diagnostics agent to do so).